Can you construct a sequence to witness that this set isn't compact?
I know that if $K$ is a closed subset of $^\omega\omega=:\mathcal{N}$ and there exists an $f\in\mathcal{N}$ such that $K\subseteq \{g\in \mathcal{N}:g\leq f \}$ (where $g\leq f$ is pointwise), then $K$ is compact. Is the converse also true?
If it is, let $U\subseteq \mathcal{N}$ such that for all $f\in\mathcal{N}$ there is a $g\in U$ that isn't dominated by $f$ i.e.$$\forall f\in\mathcal{N}:\exists g\in U:\exists n \in \omega: g(n)>f(n)$$ .
Can you construct a sequence $g_n\in U$ that has no convergent subsequnce for a given closed $U$?

What is your question? $K$ is a compact set of a metrizable space, so sequentially compact. Your question makes no sense

sorry, in previous edit I removed that part form the question by accident.

In what sense does the sequence $g_n$ has to be explicit? Surely you need to use that there exists some $g\in U$ not dominated by $f$. But this is a condition about existence, so it doesn't give you anything explicit

you are right, i removed that part from the question. I just want to construct some sequence and not argue with product topology or sth like that.

You need to argue with product topology, since this is the topology on Baire space $\mathcal{N}$

so there is no way to construct a covering just with the basic open sets?

I didn't say that. But in every argument you'd want there is a (maybe not completely explicit) usage of product topology in some way. You can't run away from it, its in the definition.

I tought that I could take the initial segments $l_n+1$ of a $g_n$. Where $g_{n}$ isn't dominated by perviously chosen $g$'s at some point $l_n$.

I don't understand your opening sentence. Let $K \subset \mathcal N$ be the subset of all $g \in \mathcal N$ with the following property: there exists $n_0$ such that $g_{n_0}=2$ and such that $g_n=1$ for all $n \ne n_0$. So $K \subseteq {g \in \mathcal N : g \le f}$ where $f$ is defined by $f(n)=2$ for all $n$. So, if your opening sentence were true, then $K$ should be compact. But $K$ does not contain $h$ defined by $h(n)=1$ for all $n$, whereas $K$ has a sequence converging to $h$. So $K$ is not compact.

Oh yes, i overread that too. He probably just forgot to write that $K$ has to be closed.

This condition is acutally equivalent to compactness in $\mathcal{N}$ for closed $K$. The proof follows immediately from the definition of the product topology. Working without it, I have to "cheat": Let $d(f,g)\colon=2^{-(n+1)}$ (where n is the first $n$ where $f$ and $g$ disagree) be a metric defined on $\mathcal{N}$. It is easy to see that the balls $B_\epsilon(f)$ are the basic clopen sets in $\mathcal{N}$.
Let $U$ be as you defined it, a set of functions that is not bounded by any other function. Every $g\in U$ must be bounded at $0$. Otherwise, choosing the basic $g_n\in U$ where $g_n(0)>n$ is a sequence with no convergent subsequence ($m\neq n\Rightarrow d(g_n,g_m) \geq 1/2$) and we are done. So $\forall g\in U: g(0)\leq n_0$ for some $n_0$ in $\omega$.
By the same argument, every $g\in U$ must be bounded at $1$ by some $n_1$. Otherwise we get another sequence  $g_n\in U$ where $g_n(0)>n$ is a sequence with no convergent subsequence ($d(g_n,g_m) \geq 1/4$) and we are done.  Inductivly, every $g\in U$ must be bounded at every $i$ by some $n_i$ , because a sequence with $g_n(i)>n$ has no convergent subsequence as $d(g_n,g_m) \geq 1/(i+1)$. Thus $U=\{f\in U:f(i)\leq n_i\}$ and this viloates your condition so one of those sequences must exist. Choose that one.

Is there any way to get a more explicit sequence than saying it is one of those?

I am not too familiar with $\mathcal{N}$. I'm sure there is something easier and more explicit.

Please don't answer poorly asked questions: EoQS

The question was if I could contruct a sequence with no convergent subsequence. I don't think that is particulary poorly asked. Working with a concrete example makes things easier.
